# Regex to extract web service name out of SOAP request

Tags: xml, regex

I'm looking to pull a the name of a web service from SOAP requests. Basically the calls look something along the lines of:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.address.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <ws:webServiceName>
             .
             .
             .
       </ws:webServiceName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried a few regexs but I can't seem to pull just the name correctly, I'd like to ignore the `<ws:` before the name, as well as the `>` character at the end. The regex: `<ws=([^>]+)` almost works, but will match `<ws:webServiceName`

Any ideas.? Thanks

Comment: `<ws:([^>]+)>` is correct, just use the group 0 instead of whole match

Comment: @ArturUdod Use the group #1 (the group #0 contains the whole match).

Comment: another "XML parsing with regexp". regexp is not for parsing XML. Use a proper XML parser instead. What will you do if the server decides to use `foo` as prefix? Add a language tag and I might give you an example how you can do it with an XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the regex flavor you're using supports lookbehinds (in this case positive lookbehinds, i.e. `(?<=...)`), this one should suit your needs:

```
(?<=<ws:)[^>]+
```